# Map multiple CSV files by header name using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am utilizing an API which unfortunately only allows me to download information in a csv format. The only option I am thinking of is to download ~100 CSV files one by one, storing each column of the csv file into an array and then deleting that CSV file when I am done with it. Each file contains the same column headers in, but they are in a different order:

```
#CSV File 1

column1 | column3 | column2

#CSV File 2

column1 | column2 | column3
```

How can I write a script to add each column to it's appropriate array (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)? I am currently artificially creating columns like so, but this is based strictly on column number, not name:

```
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = [] 

CSV.foreach(csv_file, :col_sep => "," :headers => false) do |column|  

  column1 << column[0]
  column2 << column[1]
  column3 << column[2]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CSV library, you can access each column using the name it has in the headers. So if you always have the same headers albeit in a different order, you could do that:

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, :col_sep => "," :headers => true) do |row|  
  do_whatever_you_want_with(row['your_header'])
end
```

Comment: This is what I needed - I read through the docs but didn't realize I could call rows be header names. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think the easiest thing to do would be to build a hash of arrays, like such:

```
require 'csv'

data    = Hash.new
array_of_csv_filenames.each do |file|
    csv = CSV.read(file, :headers => true)
    csv.by_col!

    csv.each do |name, values|
        data[name] = Array.new unless data[name]
        data[name].concat values
    end
end
```

And then, at the end, data will contain a hash of columns, keyed by column name.

Comment: +1 for the tips and introducing me to some new methods/ideas; however, I think for times sake it is easier for me to keep them as arrays since the rest of the script is dependent on that currently.